# Razor page always shows Production for environment variable even in visual studio IIS Express (Mac OS)

Tags: razor-pages, visual-studio-mac, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0

I am trying to load a certain script tag development and production however when I run IIS Express and output to console it is always production. Is this a glitch or am I using this incorrectly.

THanks

```
@inject Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IWebHostEnvironment env
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    @RenderSection("Styles", required: false)
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - ARMS 2.0</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/MaterialDesign-Webfont/7.2.96/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" integrity="sha512-LX0YV/MWBEn2dwXCYgQHrpa9HJkwB+S+bnBpifSOTO1No27TqNMKYoAn6ff2FBh03THAzAiiCwQ+aPX+/Qt/Ow==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vuetify/2.6.15/vuetify.css" integrity="sha512-pxgeHIBFJ56u5UVetGh9AZgTUfCp9iGqvVCRqir1/c7z+oJWm1PcDHEVieAWw+Ct8fYJxTscCG+8skxTNZKULw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-iecdLmaskl7CVkqkXNQ/ZH/XLlvWZOJyj7Yy7tcenmpD1ypASozpmT/E0iPtmFIB46ZmdtAc9eNBvH0H/ZpiBw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
</head>
<body>
    @RenderBody()
    @{
        if (string.Equals(env.EnvironmentName, "Development", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.7.14/vue.common.dev.min.js" integrity="sha512-2A6oxj7+YhJZ8H16zFL3m9eseO00e6odrsd+wQnSYiEcaw20fpsI3NSuiKQTBrGOR5ZO7xv75kjK3NZrvUTexw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
            <script>console.log("Development Mode")</script>
        }
        else
        {
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.7.14/vue.min.js" integrity="sha512-BAMfk70VjqBkBIyo9UTRLl3TBJ3M0c6uyy2VMUrq370bWs7kchLNN9j1WiJQus9JAJVqcriIUX859JOm12LWtw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
            <script>console.log("Production Mode")</script>
        }
    }
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue-router/3.6.5/vue-router.min.js" integrity="sha512-hyOQvTtBERvssSiEFSSccyA/ZImk0QLpP92CuKgClbrc72zcMRUVapwZb/6IC0669Q0GWCu4/EhswVJcC0kwXA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vuetify/2.6.15/vuetify.js" integrity="sha512-f4fOqXRzAhjcjrmGW+8X5Laqr6K4p8Y0i1IG6mN8mwuXBgf09Xgl6LQQyZZKPmOZN3IluCv/jZZG/TgOcNTSwA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/1.4.0/axios.min.js" integrity="sha512-uMtXmF28A2Ab/JJO2t/vYhlaa/3ahUOgj1Zf27M5rOo8/+fcTUVH0/E0ll68njmjrLqOBjXM3V9NiPFL5ywWPQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/3.5.141/pdf.min.js" integrity="sha512-BagCUdQjQ2Ncd42n5GGuXQn1qwkHL2jCSkxN5+ot9076d5wAI8bcciSooQaI3OG3YLj6L97dKAFaRvhSXVO0/Q==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dayjs/1.11.7/dayjs.min.js" integrity="sha512-hcV6DX35BKgiTiWYrJgPbu3FxS6CsCjKgmrsPRpUPkXWbvPiKxvSVSdhWX0yXcPctOI2FJ4WP6N1zH+17B/sAA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/PapaParse/5.4.1/papaparse.min.js" integrity="sha512-dfX5uYVXzyU8+KHqj8bjo7UkOdg18PaOtpa48djpNbZHwExddghZ+ZmzWT06R5v6NSk3ZUfsH6FNEDepLx9hPQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
    @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT*
My launchsettings.json looks as follows:

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:44361",
      "sslPort": 44362
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "DashboardProject": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:44362;http://localhost:44361",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Production"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My launchsettings does show development for that environment variable so I would think that shouldnt be an issue?

Comment: Is the environment being set elsewhere, such as in the launchSettings or via `WebApplicationOptions` perhaps? Also, I recommend you use the environment tag helper instead of the `string.Equals` approach: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/tag-helpers/environment-tag-helper

Comment: I added my launchsettings above and it shows i do set the variables. This is my _layout page so could that be effecting the environment variable somehow?

Comment: The IIS Express profile is set as Development, but the DashboardProject is set to Production. Is that the one you are running from VS? The active profile name should be visible next to the solid green triangle in the main menu at the top of your IDE.

Comment: Also - never had a Mac, but I'm pretty sure IIS Express doesn't run on that OS so I'd say its highly likely you are in fact running the DashboardProject profile. Change the environment on that profile to fix the issue.